# Error (Xcode): No such file or directory: 'WebKit'

Tags: ios, flutter, webkit, flutter-dependencies, xcode15

I'm just having a really hard time solving tis error.

**Context**: I'm running my flutter app for iOS build but its giving me this error. I've been researching for hours but couldn't find anything.

My flutter app uses google_ml_kit and flutter_mobile_vision and the same app also runs on flutter web.

[image]

**Here is my pubspec.yaml file:**
[image]

**My flutter and xcode versions**
[image]

Im running the app on iOS simulator and my **simulator** is on iOS 17.
**XCODE version:** 15.0.1 (15A507)

Comment: Do you have `webview_flutter` in your `pub spec.yaml`? I don't see in your screenshot.

Comment: @Eric i dont. and that's the most strange part. Where do this "webkit" even coming from?!!

Comment: Did you try adding `web view_flutter`? "webkit" comes from or is related with the web view.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete **Podfile.lock** file first and just go to your project directory in terminal and run this command.

- pod deintegrate
- pod install
- flutter pub get

Now run your app.

Comment: Didn't work, I tried.